# How to build a Generative AI based on insights

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, chat-bots, question-answering, natural-language-generation

I have a huge amount of documents that I do some preprocessing for them to extract insights. For instance, thousands of companies' profiles are used to extract the top N industries that exist in Japan.

Generally, if I want to build a chatbot on top of a corpus, I will fine-tune an AI model (e.g GPT) on the needed corpus and then I can ask questions like, what is the capital of Japan? etc.

But, how can I train a chatbot to answer insights questions from the companies' profiles?
I was thinking of defining what I want the chatbot to answer, and then extracting all the possible answers and transforming them into a text. Finally, fine-tune the model on the text. I feel this is going to be hard to identify what a user might ask.

Is there a better way to solve this?